# "Last-modified" date of a document through a web-browser

Tags: html, last-modified

if you inspect a document (e.g. a pdf) on a web-browser, you can obtain a "last-modified date" of the document itself:

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="http://mywebsite.org/mydocument.pdf" headers="Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 144303 Content-Type: application/pdf Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 09:09:44 GMT; Keep-Alive: timeout=6, max=70 Last-Modified: Fri, 9 Nov 2018 09:43:03 GMT Server: Apache X-Content-Type-Option: nosniff " background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" javascript="allow" full-frame="">
```

My question is: this "Last-Modified" date is referred to the time of the last change of the document as it stands before loading into the website, or to the time of load of the document into the website ?

Thank you,
best

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified):

> The Last-Modified response HTTP header contains the date and time at
>   which the origin server believes the resource was last modified.